# Why need to set server time zone after mysql8.0？

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

Before mysql8.0, mySQL did not need to set time zone, but after mysql8.0, it did.Why need to set server time zone after mysql8.0?But it wasn't needed until then.
What I mean is that when you write code, you need to add a time zone to the URL when you link to the MySQL database.
[image: when use IDEA]

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? As far as I know, MySQL Server has always had a default system-wide time zone and the installers I've used will happily default to server's time zone.

Comment: What I mean is that when you write code, you need to add a time zone to the URL when you link to the MySQL database.

Comment: What URL do you mean? Are you talking about some specific client program such as PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @nigulasiaifuge Why do you think it is "needed" to specify the timezone in the connection URL?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. I mean the URL of JDBC.

Comment: Because "Server returns invalid timezone. Neet to set 'serverTimezone' property". That wouldn't probably matter if you used a less sophisticated client that didn't do anything fancy with dates. What do you get if you run this query? `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`

Comment: OK, that is to say, this is due to the positive impact of higher version clients on date support.

Comment: Perhaps the error message is correct and the server is returning an invalid time zone. What do you get when you run `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`?